# Not able to call localhost api using Retrofit

Tags: android, rest, android-studio, localhost, retrofit2

HTTP FAILED: java.net.UnknownServiceException: CLEARTEXT communication to localhost not permitted by network security policy

Getting this above mentioned issue while calling localhost api using retrofit.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code in the android manifest file's
application tag

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```